# Override get_instance import-export django

Tags: python, django

I have a basic problem in Django/ Python. But I don't know the right answer.

I have to override "get_instance" in django-import-export.instance_loaders

Actually i change the code directly in this function. I know this is not very clever. But I don#t understand where I should override this function.

In MyModelResource or where?

Hope anybody can help me. Thanks

Comment: Why not just inherit `ModelInstanceLoader` and override this method?

Comment: How does it mean? I'm new in Python coding sorry. Can you explain please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to define custom `InstanceLoader` class in your resource inner `Meta` class:

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price',)
        instance_loader_class = MyCustomInstanceLoaderClass

class MyCustomInstanceLoaderClass(BaseInstanceLoader):
    def get_instance(self, row):
        # your implementation here
```

Something like this should help you.